# OpenGL applying filters to textures with slick.util textures

Tags: java, opengl, textures

I am learing openGL using lwjgl. I am trying to see the effects of different filters on textures. to load the textures i am using [SlickUtil.TextureLoader](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc-util/org/newdawn/slick/opengl/class-use/Texture.html) to load the textures and only the first 2 texture filter options work and the others result in a blank texture. if anyone knows what i am doing wrong or how to manually apply filters after a texture has been loaded please say so;

```
Texture[] textures = new Texture[6];
textures[0] = TextureLoader.getTexture("BMP", new FileInputStream("src/Textures/Glass.bmp"), GL_NEAREST);
textures[1] = TextureLoader.getTexture("BMP", new FileInputStream("src/Textures/Glass.bmp"), GL_LINEAR);
textures[2] = TextureLoader.getTexture("BMP", new FileInputStream("src/Textures/Glass.bmp"), GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
textures[3] = TextureLoader.getTexture("BMP", new FileInputStream("src/Textures/Glass.bmp"), GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
textures[4] = TextureLoader.getTexture("BMP", new FileInputStream("src/Textures/Glass.bmp"), GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
textures[5] = TextureLoader.getTexture("BMP", new FileInputStream("src/Textures/Glass.bmp"), GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **MIPMAP** filters require a complete mipmap chain, and it's pretty obvious that the texture loader isn't creating the mipmap chain. Mipmaps can be loaded from a file, or generated by OpenGL using glGenerateMipmap().

The usual symptom of a incomplete mipmap chain and a mipmap filter, is that the texture looks completely white (or black).

For LWJGL, you can use [glGenerateMipmap](http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL30.html#glGenerateMipmap%28int%29) (GL30, OpenGL 3.0) or [glGenerateMipmapEXT](http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/EXTFramebufferObject.html#glGenerateMipmapEXT%28int%29) (GL_EXT_framebuffer_object extension).

To use it, just bind the texture with glBindTexture, and call glGenerateMipmap with the correct texture target (the same as glBindTexture).

Comment: @stas Using glGenerateMipmap.

Comment: i checked and there is no glGenerateMipmap() method in org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11. how would i apply it to that texture anyway?

Comment: so once i callglGenerateMipmap while that texture is binded then it will perminently have that setting? could you maybe give an example? Also if you have time could you tell me why the method is in GL30 instead of GL11 and if i were to make a game should i store precalculated mipmaps in a seperate file?